# Firebase Pushing Data in One Activity and Retrieving Data in Another Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have three activities Register, Login and Main. When user enter his registration details, I am pushing the email id to firebase database after successful registration. The userdetails is successfully pushed. Now it opens MainActivity
Foll is the code in my RegisterActivity

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("loginusers");
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        saveDisplayName();

                        User user = new User(email);
                        mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(user);
    ......}
```

Now I want to retrieve all the users which are registered in my MainActivitie's ArrayList. So I wrote the foll code in my MainActivity

```
 mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("loginusers");
 mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                contactList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if(!contactList.contains(user)){
                        contactList.add(user);


                    }

                }
                for(int i=0;i<contactList.size();i++){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hi"+contactList.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("Pritish", "onDataChange: "+contactList.get(i));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {



            }
        });
```

but this method never gets called. Now I know I can write the code written in my MainActivity in RegisterActivity and then pass the userlist using an Intent, but I don't want to do that as it may create a problem if the user is using LoginActivity.
Please help

Comment: did you made logout option in your app? if logout option then you first set user  registered flag in sharedprefrence and also set login flag in shared prefrence

Comment: Didn't get you. I have not implemented logout functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to declare and use the `contactList` in the `onDataChange()` method otherwise it will be always `null` because of the asynchronous behaviour of this methods which is called even before you are adding those objects to the list. So your code should look like this:

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<User> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(!contactList.contains(user)){
                    contactList.add(user);
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<contactList.size();i++){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hi"+contactList.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("Pritish", "onDataChange: "+contactList.get(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

If you want to use the value of that String outside that method, please take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).